# Director Filmography - all queries are returning empty

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

All, I'm trying to get a director's filmography from dbpedia:

Both the queries below (and other attempts not shown) return empty sets. [Query below](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX%20d%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20?filmName%20%20WHERE%20%7B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?film%20d%3adirector%20%3awoody_allen%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?film%20rdfs%3alabel%20?filmName%20.%20%20%0D%0A%7D) doesn't work:

```
PREFIX d: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?filmName  WHERE {  
    ?film d:director :woody_allen .
    ?film rdfs:label ?filmName .  
}
```

Or (this is [from](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-wikiquery/)) :

```
PREFIX m: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?filmTitle WHERE {
  ?film rdfs:label ?filmTitle.
  ?film m:director ?dir.
  ?dir  m:director_name "Sofia Coppola".
}
```

Not sure what would be the problem with such simple queries. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your first query is the use of `:woody_allen` (besides the fact that you haven't actually defined the default prefix and so the query should technically be illegal SPARQL) the term doesn't actually appear in the data as written.

Try rewriting your query like so:

```
PREFIX d: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?filmName  WHERE {  
    ?film d:director <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Woody_Allen> .
    ?film rdfs:label ?filmName .  
}
```

The above does give results.

As for your second query DBPedia does not use the Linked MDB ontologies so that query can't match anything